# Browser-based way to push my git repo somewhere

Tags: git, bitbucket

I know well enough how to use `git push` on my CLI, but where can I go in my browser that will allow me to push my git repo (which happens to be on BitBucket) to another repo...for example if I wanted to push-to-deploy somewhere?

Again, all I have is a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but you could use [Cloud 9](https://c9.io/) to pull your code and then push it up to whatever repo you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have specified...über basic, no clunky IDE required

Comment: @themirror Yeah, I thought so. It was worth a shot... ;) Unfortuately, I'm not aware of any other existing solution.

Personally, if I were in need of something like this I'd probably just roll my own. It doesn't sound all that complicated...